# Как сделать архив данных (C#;WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня в программе есть WorkerApi и ArchiveApi
Хочу сделать что при изменение данных у рабочего старые данные записывались
К примеру:
Имя Иван
Изменили на Коля
В архив автоматически будет записано: Имя Иван заменили на Коля, у одного и тоже рабочего

```
/// Вот код по добавлению рабочего и сохранения изменений
public async Task Add()
        {
            SelectedWorker = new WorkerApi();
            var result = Api.PostAsync<WorkerApi>(SelectedWorker, "Worker");
            await GetWorkers();
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Workers)));
        }
        public async Task Save()
        {
            var oldWorker = SelectedWorker;
            var result = await Api.PutAsync<WorkerApi>(SelectedWorker, "Worker");
            await GetWorkers();
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Workers)));
        }
```

Comment: Где и как именно собираетесь хранить эти архивные данные? Правильнее их назвать "исторические". / В некоторых СУБД есть специальные возможности для этого. Например, в Sql Server есть [Temporal tables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15). В EF Core 6 появилась [поддержка](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/prime-your-flux-capacitor-sql-server-temporal-tables-in-ef-core-6-0/) таких таблиц. Рекомендую.

Comment: Можете хранить данные в ObservableCollection. Данная коллекция имеет возможность триггерить ивент изменения элемента/-ов. При замене какого-либо элемента вы можете получить и oldItem, и newItem